# C++ function that returns system date

Tags: c++

I need function in c++ that allows me to retrieve and store the system date. I have a class for storing dates.

Comment: Please try to clarify your question - I tried my best, but it's really hard to figure out what you mean. You will get better answers that way.

Comment: A question like this makes a great explanation for why C++ programmers should study C.

Comment: And the great variety of answers is a great explanation for why question askers should be *specific* about the platform they're using.

Answer (score 7):

Dealing with dates and time is difficult, thats why people use libraries. I prefer boost::date_time.

```
boost::posix_time::ptime local_time = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
boost::gregorian::date d = local_time.date();
```

d is a current date in local time, which use computer timezone settings. To get UTC time you can use *boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time()*.

Comment: I also like to use the Boost libraries as opposed to strictly using ctime and the associated functions.

Answer (score 5):

From `time.h`:

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;     /* seconds after the minute - [0,59] */
    int tm_min;     /* minutes after the hour - [0,59] */
    int tm_hour;    /* hours since midnight - [0,23] */
    int tm_mday;    /* day of the month - [1,31] */
    int tm_mon;     /* months since January - [0,11] */
    int tm_year;    /* years since 1900 */
    int tm_wday;    /* days since Sunday - [0,6] */
    int tm_yday;    /* days since January 1 - [0,365] */
    int tm_isdst;   /* daylight savings time flag */
};

time_t time(time_t * timer);
struct tm* gmtime(const time_t *timer);
struct tm* localtime(const time_t * timer);
```

Answer (score 2):

For C++ on Windows look at the Windows time [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725473(VS.85).aspx), in particular [GetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724390(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, `GetSystemTime` gives you UTC time, while to get the `TimeZone` adjusted time you need to use  `GetLocalTime`.

One more difference between WinBase time function (through windows.h) compared to time.h functions is windows time functions are reliable all the way back to **1601**, while time.h is only till **1900** onwards. I am not sure if that is something which you need to consider.

Answer (score 0):

time()

But also see localtime and asctime for display

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using (`nowtm` is populated with current system time):

```
time_t rawtime=time(NULL);
tm* nowtm = gmtime(&rawtime);
```

where tm is defined:

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;     /* seconds after the minute - [0,59] */
    int tm_min;     /* minutes after the hour - [0,59] */
    int tm_hour;    /* hours since midnight - [0,23] */
    int tm_mday;    /* day of the month - [1,31] */
    int tm_mon;     /* months since January - [0,11] */
    int tm_year;    /* years since 1900 */
    int tm_wday;    /* days since Sunday - [0,6] */
    int tm_yday;    /* days since January 1 - [0,365] */
    int tm_isdst;   /* daylight savings time flag */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote quite similar answer a few minutes ago. You can use chrono available in C++11. 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point